# Disable auto scanning for JDO classes datanucleus exploded war

Tags: jdo, datanucleus, jboss7.x

When I deploy an exploded war file datanucleus fails with following error

> Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.ClassNotResolvedException: Class "JDOTutorial.war.WEB-INF.classes.com.blogspot.jkook.daytrader.jdo.QJDOOrderData" was not found in the CLASSPATH

This does not occur when war is deployed. Seems DN is scanning for classes which use JDO annotations when loading the JCA. With exploded deployment it is scanning all the classes inside the exploded folder and fails to load since the location of the class and the class in the class path does't match. (class name is com.blogspot.jkook.daytrader.jdo.QJDOOrderData , but DN is looking for 
JDOTutorial.war.WEB-INF.classes.com.blogspot.jkook.daytrader.jdo.QJDOOrderData)

I am using settings below but DN is still scanning the exploded folder

- datanucleus.autoStartMechanism = Classes ,
- datanucleus.autoStartClassNames = com.blogspot.jkook.daytrader.jdo.JDOOrderData

Question : How to hint DN to stop scanning the exploded folders ?

Comment: Other info : jdbc driver ojdbc6.jar,datanucleus -datanucleus-jca-3.0.0-m6.rar,Jboss as 7 final,jdk 1.6,Ubuntu 8.10,Oracle 11g

Comment: I have set datanucleus.autoStartMechanismMode=Ignored in the persistance.xml but the error still exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally solved jboss has feature to add external deployment folder 
default = deployment -- placed the datanucleus-jca-3.0.0-m6 
myPath = extdeployments -- placed the JDOTutorial.war (exploded folder)

Now DN doest scan for classes inside exploder folder :)